# Sonar (JaCoCo) gives 0% coverage if my tests are not in a JUnit4 TestSuite

Tags: junit4, sonarqube, jacoco

Hi I am using sonar and I love it...

But I have a somewhat strange behavior with my latest proj.

If I put all my tests in a JUnit 4 @TestSuite JaCoCo gives me a coverage of 86,2% ( Groove baby !!! ) when I run `mvn sonar:sonar`

If I let the tests by themselves I get 0% coverage even with the Unit test success
100,0%

I don't need a TestSuite for this proj any clue about why JaCoCo is doing this?

BTW: I am using Maven 2.2.1 + Sonar 3.4.1 + sonar-maven-plugin 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to define a test suite if your tests respect the "Test*.java" & "*Test.java" naming convention.

You can have a look at the following sample application for which tests are analysed by JaCoCo: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/ut/maven/ut-maven-jacoco-runTests

Comment: The link no longer works...